# Why is $ \binom{-r}{z} = (-1)^z\binom{z+r-1}{r-1} $

Tags: binomial-coefficients

How do we prove this identity? I Can't find a simple solution.

Comment: Have you tried using the definition of the left hand side?

Answer (score 1):

$$\binom{-r}{z}=\frac{(-r)(-r-1)(-r-2)\cdots(-r-z+1)}{z!}\\=\frac{(-1)^z r(r+1)\cdots(z+r-1)}{z!}=(-1)^z\binom{z+r-1}{z}=(-1)^z\binom{z+r-1}{r-1}$$

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Why is $ \frac{r(r+1)...(z+r-1)}{z!}=\binom{z+r-1}{z} $

Comment: Rewrite it as $\frac{(z+r-1)(z+r-2)\cdots r }{z!}=\frac{(z+r-1)(z+r-2)\cdots r \, (r-1)!}{z! (r-1)!}=\frac{(z+r-1)!}{z!(r-1)!}$